# Can ORMLite work with a server?

Tags: java, ormlite

I want my java application to client to my remote server. Can I use ORMLite for this? The documentation mentions the spring framework. But a) I'm not sure how to use it and b) I don't know for sure if it works for this application.

By connecting to by server I mean I want to use the DAO to poll and push data from the database on my server (as I'm sure most client/servers do).
[image]

---

Edit: In response to Gray's follow up.

---

Before I go further into what I am confused about, I should state my understandings of what the interacting classes do.

#### JDBCConnectionSource

Is the bridge between a client (the instigator of the ConnectionSource) and a host (be it a database local or server based).

#### DAO

An interface that provides tools for easily creating SQL queries.

Now what I am still don't fully understand is the interaction of the `DAO` and the the `JdbcConnectionSource` with my server. Does the application `DAO` generate a fully "compiled" SQL statement and dispatch it to the application `ConnectionSource` for transmission to the host? The server then upon receiving the SQL request would then delegate it properly - handle the request, gather the data and return it?

Comment: Did I answer your question @Aedon?  Feel free to ask other questions i the comments below my answer.

Comment: @Gray, Your answer made me ask the right questions that led to the correct research that answered most of my questions. Thanks for that. I did edit my question with the only complication I am still having.

Comment: @Gray, Heh, ok, sorry, scratch my confusion. Epiphany moment. I understand how to make this all work now. Docs for the win.

Comment: Added more details in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean but here some general information about [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) and remoting.  ORMLite can certainly contact a remote database on a server.  All you need to do is specify your JDBC URL that points to a remote system:

```
// you can change the database type, hostname, and the database name
String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://host.name.j256.com/databaseName";
ConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);
...
```

You can certainly use Spring for this but it is not a requirement.  If you mean to contact a server using some sort of HTTP, RMI, or other remoting mechanism, then you will have to write the client/server wrappers for that.  ORMLite does not provide any remoting aside from that provided by JDBC.

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**

`JDBCConnectionSource` is the implementation of the `ConnectionSource` interface that uses [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to talk to the database.  There is also `AndroidConnectionSource` which uses direct database calls under AndroidOS.

The `ConnectionSource` is, shockingly, the source of connections to the database.  You can see the various methods by [looking at its javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource.html).  The most use methods are:
`getReadOnlyConnection()`, `getReadWriteConnection()`, and `releaseConnection`.  This does not do any remoting itself.  It lets the JDBC do the actual connecting and remoting to the database server, whether local or remote.

The `Dao` interface provides the tools to do all of the operations with the database.  It uses the `ConnectionSource` to get a connection to the database, performs an operation (insert, delete, update, select), and then releases the database connection.

> Now what I am still don't fully understand is the interaction of the DAO and the the JdbcConnectionSource with my server. Does the application DAO generate a fully "compiled" SQL statement and dispatch it to the application ConnectionSource for transmission to the host?

No.  ORMLite generates the SQL necessary to do the operation, it gets a connection to the database from the `ConnectionSource`, it compiles the SQL and sets any arguments using the connection, it executes the statement using the connection, it processes the results, and then releases the connection.

Comment: Exactly what I [suddenly] figured. Dug more around the docs to see the interactions of the classes, then pried open the source to see exactly how you made the base implementations. Once I did that the entire system made sense. I believe that my confusion came from the fact that I thought the API did <em>everything</em> behind the scenes and I could remain hands off. As it turns out, I can't be as lazy as I hoped :-p. Thanks for your help.